# How to automatically update a list of filenames in Python

Tags: python, io

I have a list of filenames: `files = ["untitled.txt", "example.txt", "alphabet.txt"]`
I also have a function to create a new file:

```
def create_file(file):
"""Creates a new file."""
with open(file, 'w') as nf:
    is_first_line = True
    while True:
        line = input("Line? (Type 'q' to quit.) ")
        if line == "q":
            # Detects if the user wants to quuit.
            time.sleep(5)
            sys.exit()
        else:
            line = line + "\n"
            if is_first_line == False:
                nf.write(line)
            else:
                nf.write(line)
                is_first_line = False
```

I want the list to update itself after the file is created. However, if I just `filenames.append()` it,
I realized that it would only update itself for the duration of the program. Does anybody know how to do this? Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is this possible in Python?" -> This has nothing to do with limitations of the language you chose to solve your problem. What you want here is persistence. You could just store the list of files in a text file. Instead of hardcoding the list in your code your program would then read the content every time it is run.

This code could get you started:

```py
with open("files.txt") as infile:
    files = [f.strip() for f in infile.readlines()]
print(f"files: {files}")

# here do some stuff and create file 'new_file'
new_file = 'a_new_file.txt'
files.append(new_file)
###

with open("files.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(files))
```

Comment: Of course you _can_. See new example added to my answer.

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot about that. Thanks!

Comment: The example code will add 'a_new_file.txt' to the end of the file 'files.txt' during each run. To get started, create file files.txt with untitled.txt, example.txt, alphabet.txt each on a separate line.